# how to save multiple model-forms (which are in 1:1) simultaneously in a view (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, foreign-keys

how to save multiple model-forms (lAWYER AND CATEGORY) (which are in 1:1) simultaneously in a view (Django)

```
class Lawyer(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='lawyer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='profiles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

class Category(models.Model):
profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
category_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_index=True,choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True, db_index=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**IN VIEWS.PY**

```
def lawyer_list(request, category_slug=None):

if request.method == 'POST':
    cat_form = CategoryForm(request.POST)
    if cat_form.is_valid():
        cat_obj = cat_form.save(commit=False)
        cat_obj.profile = request.user.profile
        cat_obj.save()
    lawyer_form = LawyerForm(request.POST)
    if lawyer_form.is_valid():
        lawyer_form = lawyer_form.save(commit=False)
        lawyer_form.profile = request.user.profile
        lawyer_form.category = cat_obj
        lawyer_form.save()
```

ALSO HAVE TWO FORMS 
1) class LawyerForm(forms.ModelForm)
2)class CATEGORYForm(forms.ModelForm)

IN VIEWS I DONT WANT TO MAKE TWO OBJECT

**Forms.py**

```
enter code here
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (('CRIMINAL', 'Criminal'),('EMPLOYMENT', 'Employment'),
('CORPORATE', 'Corporate'),)


class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

category_name = forms.CharField(max_length=3,
                           widget=forms.Select(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES),)

class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ('category_name','city',)


class LawyerForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Lawyer
    fields = ('name','description','charge','available',)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Lawyer(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='lawyer',   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='profiles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_index=True,choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True, db_index=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        lawyer=Lawyer(*args,**kwargs)
        lawyer.category=self
        lawyer.save()
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

in views

```
def lawyer_list(request, category_slug=None):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        cat_form = CategoryForm(request.POST)
        if cat_form.is_valid():
            cat_obj = cat_form.save(commit=False)
            cat_obj.profile = request.user.profile
            cat_obj.save()
```